# Django many to many relations

Tags: django, database-design, django-models

I currently have three models, but I'm not really sure how to design this the best. One is the `Song` model, one is the `Artist` and finally the `Show` model

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Show(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    artist = models.ManyToManyField('Artist')
    show = models.ManyToManyField('Show')
    duration = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s (%s)' % (self.title, [artist.name for artist in self.artist.all()], self.duration)
```

The things I wasn't sure about are the relations. A artist has songs, but a song can also have multiple artists, and a show can (or always has) multiple songs and songs can be in multiple shows essentially. What would be the right design here with the `ManyToMany` fields?

Comment: I am not sure what does your model "Show" represent, please clarify. So you are going to duplicate a "Song" for every performance on every show? That doesn't seem wise. I would suggest using a model like ShowPerformance that links a song and a show.

Answer (score 1):

On database level it's pretty obvious: `Artist (M:N) Song (M:N) Show`. This implements situations you described and also assumes that an `Artist` is participating in a `Show` only through singing a `Song` (he can not participate without performing something).

The model will probably go like this:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    songs = models.ManyToManyField('Song')

class Song(models.Model):
    artists = models.ManyToManyField('Artist')
    shows = models.ManyToManyField('Show')

class Show(models.Model):
    songs = models.ManyToManyField('Song')
```

Answer (score 0):

For this each individual can have different views, according to me this will help you,

Relationships in your models-

1. Artist- (O:M) ->Song
2. Song- (M:O) ->Artist
3. Show- (O:M) ->Songs
4. Song- (M:M) ->Show

:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    artist = models.ManyToManyField('Artist')
    duration = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Show(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    song = models.ManyToManyField('Song')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```